# How can I get random id that firebase generated?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get firebase generated random ids.
For better understanding I share screenshoots of collections on firebase.[image]
[image]

I want to get the data that I show with red arrow.

I tried to get this value like that :

```
newsCollection
        .doc('dunya')
        .collection('haberler')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        return News.fromFirestore(doc.data());
      }).toList();
    });
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/id.html

Comment: As Doug commented and linked, that value is available as `doc.id` in your `map` callback.